# Force release key with hwdb

Tags: systemd, keyboard, udev

I've got new keyboard and mute key is not sending release event. From what I've been reading in hwdb it is possible to make driver send synthetic release event and I've tried to make it do so.

Here are my steps:

1. Using evtest and evemu-describe I've found out which key and which device should be configured.
2. Made a record in `/lib/udev/hwdb.d/90-custom-keyboard.hwdb`:

   ```
   evdev:input:b0003v0C45p7903*
     KEYBOARD_KEY_c00e2=!mute
   ```
3. Did `systemd-hwdb update`, rebuilt initrd `mkinicpio -p linux`.
4. Rebooted and checked `udevadm info` shows correct values

   ```
   P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:06:00.0/0000:07:01.0/0000:09:00.0/0000:0a:02.0/0000:0d:00.0/usb5/5-3/5-3:1.1/0003:0C45:7903.0006/input/input26/event25
   N: input/event25
   S: input/by-id/usb-SONiX_USB_DEVICE-event-if01
   S: input/by-path/pci-0000:0d:00.0-usb-0:3:1.1-event
   E: DEVLINKS=/dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:0d:00.0-usb-0:3:1.1-event /dev/input/by-id/usb-SONiX_USB_DEVICE-event-if01
   E: DEVNAME=/dev/input/event25
   E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:06:00.0/0000:07:01.0/0000:09:00.0/0000:0a:02.0/0000:0d:00.0/usb5/5-3/5-3:1.1/0003:0C45:7903.0006/input/input26/event25
   E: ID_BUS=usb
   E: ID_INPUT=1
   E: ID_INPUT_KEY=1
   E: ID_MODEL=USB_DEVICE
   E: ID_MODEL_ENC=USB\x20DEVICE
   E: ID_MODEL_ID=7903
   E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:0d:00.0-usb-0:3:1.1
   E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_0d_00_0-usb-0_3_1_1
   E: ID_REVISION=0110
   E: ID_SERIAL=SONiX_USB_DEVICE
   E: ID_TYPE=hid
   E: ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
   E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030101:030102:
   E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=01
   E: ID_VENDOR=SONiX
   E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=SONiX
   E: ID_VENDOR_ID=0c45
   E: KEYBOARD_KEY_c00e2=!mute
   E: LIBINPUT_DEVICE_GROUP=3/c45/7903:usb-0000:0d:00.0-3
   E: MAJOR=13
   E: MINOR=89
   E: SUBSYSTEM=input
   E: TAGS=:power-switch:
   E: USEC_INITIALIZED=5143289
   ```

   Note the KEYBOARD_KEY_c00e2 - so it was loaded.
5. Tested if it works with evtest and it didn't :(

Seems that despite proper configuration as described in hwdb force-release attribute was not populated, which is confirmed by `udevadm info -a -p /sys/class/input/event25 | grep -i force.release` - no such attribute was set.

What am I doing wrong? How do I make driver to send synthetic release event right after press?

Versions:
Systemd: 239
Kernel: 4.18.8

Thank you.

Comment: This is a media key and keyboard seems to don't send release event at all. Hence I need to fix it somehow at software side.

Comment: Are you *sure* the scancode is `c00e2`? This looks very large for a scancode. How did you determine the scancode? `evtest`?

Comment: Yes, I've been using `evtest`: `Event: time 1537625653.354219, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value c00e2`